# How to read what's inside a specific memory address to debug crashes of a software?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, crash, except

I am trying to debug a 2009 made game file that randomly crashes without no error or anything other than 0xblabla at game.exe 0x00000005: unable to read at 0xblabla

So I want to see what's inside that adress that can't be read by process. I already tried with writing my own c# program to see it but it also denies access to read that address too.

Game is made in c++ btw.

Comment: When you get an access violation crash, the address that was being accessed which produced the violation is not a valid address in the process' memory space. There won't be anything to look at there.

Comment: Attach a debugger. The chances are though that address doesn’t exist which is why you have an error in the first place.

Comment: I attached VS debugger, that's how I learned about address.
Do I have a chance to see what does process do that makes it crash without access to source code?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what would your suggestion be?

Comment: @user110766 If you have the source code, attach a debugger and see what is happening. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do. You can try to debug the assembly, but that is a lot of work. I suspect this is a dead end.